# Hover to href img src?

Tags: hover, image, href

Hey i have been trying this for a while but with no luck.
I have the following code:

`<a href="iframelink opened in fancybox"><img src="image link"></a>`

How can i apply an image hover to the img src? Thanks

Comment: CSS, JS ... what's your idea? what is your idea saying `How can i apply an image hover`?

Comment: I would avoid js but the idea is to add a hover to the image link that opens an iframe fancybox. But if there is no other way, i will use js.

Comment: add `title="..."` to the `a` and `img` - this will show you a hover? is that your idea?

Comment: Using the css ":hover" property to change the image link

Comment: I tired calling all the classes and id's but the hovering effect is under the img src rendering it useless.

Comment: you can not change image src with CSS ... if i correctly understand your idea ... but you can change the background so if you make your image as background you can change it ver easy using CSS. Do you need an example?

Comment: Yeah show me an example please.

Comment: ok, I've posted an answer giving a basic example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of using background image instead of an `<img>` tag.

```
<a href="...." rel="fancybox"><a>
```

CSS:

```
a[rel=fancybox] {
  display: block;
  background: url('image1.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
}

a[rel=...]:hover {
  background: url('image2.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
}
```

You may need to preload your images.

using JS:

```
<a href="" rel="" onmouseover="this.getElementById('i1').src='/images/image_hover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.getElementById('i1').src='/images/image.jpg'">
<img id="i1" src="/images/image.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: Ok that done the trick. Thank you so much !

Comment: Goood! I am bookmarking this, so mods please don't delete this topic!

Comment: no worries, yu can try the JS one too ...  should work.